Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted] in BNB
I have a problem with creating listing on marketplace in BNB chain.
I am using ThirdWeb sdk.
When I create listing, the transaction fails.
Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [execution reverted]
https://testnet.bscscan.com/tx/0xeffc08e1a01e86e87ae8f83e61398f66b4a21fdc518cb0348c812290a56af983
This is code.
  const listingData = {
    assetContractAddress: nft.contract,
    tokenId: String(nft.identifier),
    quantity: "1",
    pricePerToken: data.price,
    startTimestamp: new Date(data.startDate),
    endTimestamp: new Date(data.endDate),
    currencyContractAddress: TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
    isReservedListing: false,
  };
  );
  const txResult = await marketplace?.directListings.createListing(
    listingData
  );

I want your help. Thank you.
